# How to keep uploaded image from user in memory with flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to build a website where the user uploads an image with text on it. The image should then be kept in memory. After that the website sholud get the text from the image and read it out.

Until now the user is only able to upload the image but nothing happens with it beacause I still have no submit button. So I basically only have an html code with an upload button.

For this I wanted to use python so maybe a flask app. But is it possible to somehow tell the flask app to keep the image in memory so I don't have to store it? If yes how? And if not do you maybe have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

I am still a total beginner and am trying to learn so excuse me if there are any logical mistakes in my question. And thanks in advance for any answers or suggestions.

Comment: Whatever you have as a value in any programming language is stored in memory

Comment: You should probably use `global` values. Although usage of global variables is often discouraged.

Answer (score -2):

you can do this

```
from flask import Flask
from PIL import Image
import secrets
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

def save_image(index):
    rn = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _,f = os.path.splitext(index.filename)
    filename = rn + f
    path = os.path.join(app.root_path, "static/", filename)
    i = Image.open(index)
    i.save(path)
    return filename
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.